# Find bluetooth version on Galaxy S3 running 4.3

Tags: bluetooth, 4.3-jelly-bean

Every answer I've found to this question says that under Settings -> About Phone, I should see Bluetooth Version listed. I don't even have About Phone. There's Settings -> More -> About Device, which shows me the android version and kernel version, but nothing about bluetooth. If I then click on Status (on the About Device page) I get my bluetooth address, but again, not the version. Help?

Answer (score 2):

The option you are citing is the very same. Whether it says "About phone" or "About device" is usually dependent of whether it's a phone or a tablet. Obviously Samsung "thinks big".

To your main issue: You might be able to use a Bluetooth device scanner on your PC to give you details on "devices in reach". Details should at least give you clues, so e.g. "EDR" is not available before BT 2.0, SSP was added with 2.1, etc. (see [Wikipedia on Bluetooth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth)).

On the other hand, checking the [S3 specs at GSMArena.Com](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_i9300_galaxy_s_iii-4238.php) (first address when looking for device specs) shows:

> **Bluetooth:** Yes, v4.0 with A2DP, EDR

Which should answer your question.